# Tomcat8 Springboot not reading application.properties

Tags: java, spring, logging, application.properties

I'm working with java spring for the first time on a personal project and I can't seem to get any of the properties in application.properties to work correctly.  I've simplified it down to this test case and it doesn't seem to be doing anything:

application.properties

```
logging.level.root=WARN
```

AppInitalizer.java:

```
import javax.servlet.Filter;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


@SpringBootApplication
@ConfigurationProperties
public class AppInitializer
    extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppInitializer.class);

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        log.debug("This is a debug message");
        log.error("This is an error message");
        return new Class[] {};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        return new Filter[] {};
    }
}
```

Log after deploy:

```
20:08:26.113 [http-nio-8080-exec-32] DEBUG AppInitializer - This is a debug message
20:08:26.114 [http-nio-8080-exec-32] ERROR AppInitializer - This is an error message
```

The two files are deployed to the same directory at the root of the classpath.

Only the second log message should be showing but I can't take care of the first.

Relevant ivy.xml config:

```
<!-- Spring Framework -->
<dependency org="org.springframework"
            name="spring-webmvc" rev="5.0.9.RELEASE"/>
<!-- Logging -->
<dependency org="log4j" name="log4j" rev="1.2.17"/>
```

Edit: I switched out my logger to slf4j and still not luck.

Edit2: Added dependencies

Edit3: I was looking through he log and found this:

```
10:28:22.628 [http-nio-8080-exec-114] INFO org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
10:28:22.634 [http-nio-8080-exec-114] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding PropertySource 'servletConfigInitParams' with lowest search precedence
10:28:22.634 [http-nio-8080-exec-114] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding PropertySource 'servletContextInitParams' with lowest search precedence
10:28:22.636 [http-nio-8080-exec-114] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding PropertySource 'jndiProperties' with lowest search precedence
10:28:22.636 [http-nio-8080-exec-114] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding PropertySource 'systemProperties' with lowest search precedence
10:28:22.636 [http-nio-8080-exec-114] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding PropertySource 'systemEnvironment' with lowest search precedence
10:28:22.636 [http-nio-8080-exec-114] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment - Initialized StandardServletEnvironment with PropertySources [StubPropertySource@36449077 {name='servletConfigInitParams', properties=java.lang.Object@24214aae}, StubPropertySource@1983551321 {name='servletContextInitParams', properties=java.lang.Object@6e836355}, JndiPropertySource@219519027 {name='jndiProperties', properties=org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate@234fc705}, MapPropertySource@23923818 {name='systemProperties', properties={awt.toolkit=sun.awt.X11.XToolkit, java.specification.version=10, file.encoding.pkg=sun.io, sun.cpu.isalist=, sun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8, java.class.path=/usr/share/tomcat8/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat8/bin/tomcat-juli.jar, java.vm.vendor=Oracle Corporation, sun.arch.data.model=64, java.vendor.url=http://java.oracle.com/, catalina.useNaming=true, user.timezone=America/Los_Angeles, os.name=Linux, java.vm.specification.version=10, sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD, user.country=US, sun.boot.library.path=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib, sun.java.command=org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start, jdk.debug=release, sun.cpu.endian=little, user.home=/var/lib/tomcat8, user.language=en, java.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.apache.naming, java.version.date=2018-07-17, java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64, ignore.endorsed.dirs=, file.separator=/, java.vm.compressedOopsMode=32-bit, line.separator=
10:28:22.639 [http-nio-8080-exec-114] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment - Replacing PropertySource 'servletContextInitParams' with 'servletContextInitParams'
10:28:22.639 [http-nio-8080-exec-114] INFO org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Jan 15 10:28:22 PST 2019]; root of context hierarchy
```

None of the property sources seem to be loading from the classpath which is where I have the application.properties.

Comment: I would suggest you to directly run your `AppInitializer` without creating a WAR and deploying it. SpringBoot comes with integrated Tomcat/Jetty which will be ready to use. In that way, you can debug your issue more easily

Comment: Can you give an example on how to do that?  I'm not using an IDE, maven, or gradle.  The docs say I can run it from a jar but it doesn't say what the layout of that jar should be.

Answer (score 1):

Please use slf4j.Logger over apache.commons.logging

Answer (score 1):

Use slf4j's [LoggerFactory](https://springframework.guru/using-logback-spring-boot/) instead of `org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory`:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
```

Or static logger:

```
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppInitializer.class);
```

Comment: @user2752635 can you show more relevant log configuration as in pom for example?

Comment: I'm not using maven.  I have an ivy.xml file which ant uses to download dependencies.  Did you want to see that?

Comment: I added the bootstrap and logging portion of the ivy.xml

Answer (score -1):

1. Spring has also introduces the new @PropertySource annotation, as a convenient mechanism for adding property sources to the environment. This annotation is to be used in conjunction with Java based configuration and the @Configuration annotation:

   @Configuration
   @PropertySource("classpath:foo.properties")
   public class AppInitializer{
       //...
   }
2. One other very useful way of registering a new properties file is using a placeholder to allow you to dynamically select the right file at runtime; for example:

   @PropertySource({ 
         "classpath:persistence-${envTarget:mysql}.properties"
      })
3. You can use in XML, new properties files can be made accessible to Spring via the  namespace element:

The foo.properties file should be placed under /src/main/resources so that it will be available on the classpath at runtime.